# Tumblr site responsive in browser, not on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css, responsive-design

I've done [my own customization](http://levicallaway.tumblr.com/) on a custom responsive theme for Tumblr, and it seems to work like a champ when resizing in a desktop browser, plus on three different responsive test sites I've used. When I load it up on my iPhone 5, however, the Photoset breaks the right side of the container and continues offscreen.

I've tried all the solutions I've seen online, including making sure I've got the viewport tag in the head, ensuring there aren't two viewport tags, adding an iPhone-specific media query that sets a max-width for the Photoset div, etc. I'm using Tumblr's own responsive variable for the Photoset post type ({Photoset}) in what I think is the right way (it's how it was initially set up in the theme, but I replaced {Photoset-700} with {Photoset} to get the responsive functionality).

I'm officially at a loss. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: iPhone native screen resolution is `320px`. Your responsive design only breaks down to `406px`. Perhaps add a media query to combat this?

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas! I've tried adding an iPhone-specific query, but I guess the problem I'm running into is that I don't know what specific element is causing the photoset to break its container. I've tried max-limiting the width of the photoset div, content div etc. for iPhone and nothing works. This was all done using Safari Web Inspector on the actual device.

Comment: I'm not sure. The static `H1` size of your title with the word `adventures`... could that be causing the issue?